# Sort list of strings as BigDecimal in reverse order in Java

Tags: java

I need to sort list of strings comparing them as BigDecimal. Here is what I tried:

```java
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(s -> new BigDecimal(s))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new).reversed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can I somehow do this without explicitly specifying the types?

Comment: What problems are you having? Can you show the list of values?  And the types are BigDecimal so if you want to sort them as that you have to treat them as such.

Comment: If the type is not specified explicitly, how the compiler should guess that the strings need to be sorted as `BigDecimal`?  It may sort strings as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
List<String> strings = List.of("123.33", "332.33");
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(BigDecimal::new, Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sortedStrings);
```

prints

```
[332.33, 123.33]
```

You could also do it like this but need to declare the type parameter as a String.

```
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((String p)->new BigDecimal(p)).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But here is the way I would recommend doing it. BigDecimal implements the `Comparable` interface.  So you simply map all the values to `BigDecimal`, sort them in reverse order, and then convert back to a String.  Otherwise, the other solutions will continue to instantiate a `BigDecimal` object just for sorting and that could result in many instantiations.

```
List<String> sortedStrings = strings
        .stream()
        .map(BigDecimal::new)
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .map(BigDecimal::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(sortedStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that can sort anything by converting it to another class you should just have the following `sortWithConverter` function

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    static public <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<T> sortWithConverter(List<T> unsorted, Function<T, U> converter) {
        return unsorted
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(converter).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("5");
        strings.add("1");
        strings.add("2");
        strings.add("7");
        System.out.println(sortWithConverter(strings, BigDecimal::new));
    }
}
```

This program prints: `[7, 5, 2, 1]`